# Why new image is available from Portal, but not from SDK listing?

Tags: image, azure, sdk

I have 2 Windows images:

Image A - was created couple of months ago

Image B - was created today

Steps I used to create Image B described here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/17/step-by-step-templating-vms-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-and-powershell-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-17-of-31.aspx

I use these images to create new VMs using Ruby SDK libraries.
All is working as expected with Image A from both Portal and SDK.
In case with Image B it is only works from Portal, but not SDK.
SDK is throws "The virtual machine image source is not valid." message.

Further debugging of SDK call showed that Image B is not present in the list, but it is present in the list on Portal...

The only difference I noticed between Image A and Image B is that on IMAGES tab Image A has Source set to "-" and Image B is pointing to Cloud Service where VM used for image customization was hosted. And deletion of Cloud Service B did not change Source information for Image B to "-".

Can some one tell why new image is available from Portal, but not from SDK listing?

Answer (score 0):

The ruby sdk is, sadly, missing that feature... You have to use the RESTful API to get them.

Refer [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499770.aspx) for the details, but suffice it to say, here is a rough snippet of code to get you going:

```
def get(uri)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  pem = File.read('/path/to/management_cert')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
  http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem)
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  request['x-ms-version'] = '2014-06-01'
  request['Content-Length'] = 0

  http.request(request)
end
```

And here is how to invoke the above method (Specific to listing images)...

```
get 'https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/vmimages'
```

Be sure to place your subscription id in the noted place in the url above.

Also, this (thankfully) will give you a list of ONLY your images... You still use the sdk to get the rest... Refer to the link above to view the xml schema for the response.